# How to detect url format using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to detect url format using javascript ?

I tried with my code but not work, what wrong.

When i test my code it's not alert . How can i do ?

```
function ValidURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\/\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\d]([a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])*)\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\:\d+)?(\/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\?[;&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\#[-a-z\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locater
  if(!pattern.ValidURL(str)) 
  {
    alert("Please enter a valid URL.");
    //return false;
  } 
  else
  {
    alert("it's good");
    //return true;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/18wz1xto/1/

Comment: have yo checked the developer tools console for errors?

Comment: In the fiddle, you can't pass an unquoted string to a function. Use single quotes within a double-quoted attribute string, or vice versa.

Comment: show this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(https?://)?((([a-zd]([a-zd-]*[a-zd])*).)+[a-z]{2,}|((d{1,3}.){3}d{1,3}))(:d+)?(/[-a-zd%_.~+]*)*(?[;&a-zd%_.~+=-]*)?(#[-a-zd_]*)?$/: Invalid group`

Comment: because you're creating the RegExp using a string, you need to double escape ... `\\d` instead of `\d` for example

Comment: also, to make it work in jsfiddle, you need to set the javascript to "No Wrap - in head"

Comment: You can't expect `pattern.ValidURL(str)` to work.  I think you mean `pattern.test(str)`.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code 
The problem is here 
The question mark is not escaped

Your code

```
'(\?[;&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
```

Corrected code:

```
"(\\?[;&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?"+ // query string
```

That's the reason you getting the error and alert is not triggering.

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/18wz1xto/6/)

It does not test the url correctly coz the regex need to be tweaked.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your function has to pass the argument in quotes `'` and the regular expression in string has to escape `\` again with a `\`. Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/18wz1xto/4/).

**HTML:**

```
<div onclick="ValidURL('http://www.google.com')">check url format</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function ValidURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locater
  if(!pattern.test(str)) 
  {
    alert("Please enter a valid URL.");
    //return false;
  } 
  else
  {
    alert("it's good");
    //return true;
  }
}
```